# Finding variation between each element in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following array:

```
list1 = [2.11e-06, 2.03e-06, 2.24e-06, 2.04e-06, 3.01e-06, 1.62e-06, 1.82e-06, 1.67e-06, 1.75e-06, 1.67e-06, 1.71e-06, 1.69e-06, 1.87e-06, 1.75e-06, 1.75e-06, 1.75e-06, 1.85e-06, 1.75e-06, 2.03e-06, 1.78e-06, 1.93e-06, 1.75e-06, 1.75e-06, 1.75e-06, 2.19e-06, 2.28e-06, 2.13e-06, 2.92e-06, 2.14e-06, 2.24e-06, 2.06e-06, 2.21e-06, 2.17e-06, 2.17e-06, 2.41e-06, 2.41e-06, 2.03e-06, 2.42e-06]
```

I'm trying to get a new array, where each element is the variation between an element and its next element. So for example if I have `[1, 2, 1]`, I need to get: `[100, -50]`.

Here is what I tried:

```
for x in list1[1:]:
    PreviousIndex = list1.index(x)-1
    Variation = ((x - list1[PreviousIndex])/list1[PreviousIndex])*100
    NewArr.append(Variation)
```

Which will give the following output:

```
[-12.8099173553719, -3.7914691943128, 10.344827586206902, -8.928571428571438, 47.54901960784314, -46.179401993355484, 12.345679012345679, -8.241758241758234, 4.790419161676638, -8.241758241758234, 2.395209580838313, -1.1695906432748548, 10.650887573964509, 4.790419161676638, 4.790419161676638, 4.790419161676638, 5.714285714285721, 4.790419161676638, -3.7914691943128, -12.315270935960598, 8.426966292134846, 4.790419161676638, 4.790419161676638, 4.790419161676638, 25.142857142857157, 4.109589041095889, -6.578947368421064, 37.08920187793427, -26.712328767123296, 10.344827586206902, -8.035714285714283, 7.281553398058244, -1.8099547511312237, -1.8099547511312237, 11.059907834101375, 11.059907834101375, -3.7914691943128, 19.211822660098527]
```

The problem with this implementation is that at a certain point I have, on `list1`, two consecutive same elements `1.75e-06, 1.75e-06`, so I should get a `0.0` Variation, but I'm not getting it.
Does anyone know a smoother implementation for this simple problem?

Comment: Can you post some of the surrounding code for what you tried?

Comment: What do you mean? There is the complete output of this code

Comment: Sorry, missed that.

Comment: No problem! Question should be ok now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `list1.index(x)` is the index of the *first* occurrence of `x` in the list. If you have repeats, the following values will get the index of the first and you will will use that first value's predecessor multiple times.

You could just enumerate the array by index instead.

```
list1 = [2.11e-06, 2.03e-06, 2.24e-06, 2.04e-06, 3.01e-06, 1.62e-06, 1.82e-06,
    1.67e-06, 1.75e-06, 1.67e-06, 1.71e-06, 1.69e-06, 1.87e-06, 1.75e-06, 
    1.75e-06, 1.75e-06, 1.85e-06, 1.75e-06, 2.03e-06, 1.78e-06, 1.93e-06, 
    1.75e-06, 1.75e-06, 1.75e-06, 2.19e-06, 2.28e-06, 2.13e-06, 2.92e-06, 
    2.14e-06, 2.24e-06, 2.06e-06, 2.21e-06, 2.17e-06, 2.17e-06, 2.41e-06, 
    2.41e-06, 2.03e-06, 2.42e-06]

NewArr = []

for i in range(len(list1) -1 ):
    prev = list1[i]
    cur = list1[i+1]
    Variation = ((cur-prev)/prev)*100
    NewArr.append(Variation)

for i, item in enumerate(NewArr):
    print(i, item)
```

You could also do this with `numpy` which will apply operations to entire arrays in one step:

```
arr = np.array(list1)
cur = arr[1:]
prev = arr[:-1]
new_arr = ((cur-prev)/prev) * 100
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `zip` in order to traverse the list and use list comprehension to create the result as follow:

```
list1 = [2.11e-06, 2.03e-06, 2.24e-06, 2.04e-06, 3.01e-06, 1.62e-06, 1.82e-06, 1.67e-06, 1.75e-06, 1.67e-06, 1.71e-06, 1.69e-06, 1.87e-06, 1.75e-06, 1.75e-06, 1.75e-06, 1.85e-06, 1.75e-06, 2.03e-06, 1.78e-06, 1.93e-06, 1.75e-06, 1.75e-06, 1.75e-06, 2.19e-06, 2.28e-06, 2.13e-06, 2.92e-06, 2.14e-06, 2.24e-06, 2.06e-06, 2.21e-06, 2.17e-06, 2.17e-06, 2.41e-06, 2.41e-06, 2.03e-06, 2.42e-06]

result = [(b - a)/a*100 for a, b in zip(list1[::], list1[1::])]
print(result)
```

Result would be:

```
[-3.7914691943128, 10.344827586206902, -8.928571428571438, 47.54901960784314, -46.179401993355484, 12.345679012345679, -8.241758241758234, 4.790419161676638, -4.571428571428564, 2.395209580838313, -1.1695906432748548, 10.650887573964509, -6.417112299465247, 0.0, 0.0, 5.714285714285721, -5.405405405405411, 16.000000000000004, -12.315270935960598, 8.426966292134846, -9.32642487046633, 0.0, 0.0, 25.142857142857157, 4.109589041095889, -6.578947368421064, 37.08920187793427, -26.712328767123296, 4.672897196261697, -8.035714285714283, 7.281553398058244, -1.8099547511312237, 0.0, 11.059907834101375, 0.0, -15.767634854771776, 19.211822660098527]
```

I think in `[1, 2, 1]` the result would be `[100.0, -50.0]` and not `[100.0, -100.0]`, please give a feedback to make corrections if I was wrong